# How to find documents that contain an array field with all elements that matches all the specified query criteria

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like this:

```
{ 
  "_id" : XXXXX,
  "players" : [
      { 
        "name": xxx,
        "status" : 0,
        ...
       },
       { 
        "name": xxx,
        "status" : 1,
        ...
       },
       ...
    ],
    "else":XXXXX
}
{ 
  "_id" : XXXXX,
  "players" : [
      { 
        "name": xxx,
        "status" : 0,
        ...
       },
       { 
        "name": xxx,
        "status" : 0,
        ...
       },
       ...
    ],
    "else":XXXXX
}
```

I want to find all the documents that in the Players array, all the status is 0.
I tried
    `db.data.find({"players.status":{$all :[0]}})`
and 
    `db.data.find({"players":{$elemMatch : { "status" : 0}}})` those only give me documents that contain an array field with at least one elements that matches all the specified query criteria.

What can I do???

Answer (score 0):

Based on your document, I created a collection with below documents.

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "players" : [
        {
            "name" : 11,
            "status" : 0
        },
        {
            "name" : 22,
            "status" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "players" : [
        {
            "name" : 33,
            "status" : 0
        },
        {
            "name" : 44,
            "status" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

The elemsMatch filter return all the array elements when one of the elements match the filter criteria - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch

You can use use elemMatch with projection, to return only a single element from the array - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

```
db.data.find({"players.status" : 0},{"players":{$elemMatch : { "status" : 0}}})
```

The above query will return one array element for each document.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "players" : [ { "name" : 11, "status" : 0 } ] } 
{ "_id" : 2, "players" : [ { "name" : 33, "status" : 0 } ] }
```

But if you expect multiple array elements to match the criteria, then you can use below Aggregation query.

```
db.data.aggregate([
    // 3rd step will do the work, but for performence benefit - Match to reduce the docs which has one or more array elements with players.status = 0
    {$match : { "players.status" : 0 }},

    // Unwind the players array
    {$unwind : "$players"},

    // Match players.status = 0
    {$match : { "players.status" : 0 }},

    // Group the docs based on _id and push the players doc(from unwind) with status = 0, to the players array 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "players": { "$push": "$players" }
    }}
])
```

The result of above aggragtion query is -

```
{ "_id" : 1, "players" : [ { "name" : 11, "status" : 0 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "players" : [ { "name" : 33, "status" : 0 }, { "name" : 44, "status" : 0 } ] }
```

Comment: Based on your data, how can I only return "_id":1 item ? because I only want the element who's players status are all 0 ,

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question - I thought you wanted only array docs which has status as 0. The algo can be like count the total array element and array element that has status as 0. I'm not able to think this using Aggregate. Probably you need to handle this using shell script or in programming language from which you are connecting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine `$all` with `$elemMatch`, something like this may do the trick:

```
db.data.find({ "players": { "$all": { "$elemMatch": { "status": 0 } } } });
```

Comment: I tried in my database ```db.match.find({ "players": { "$all": [{ "$elemMatch": { "leaver_status": 0 } }] } }).count()``` and ```db.match.find({"players.leaver_status":{$all :[0]}}).count()``` gives me same numbers. And the number was not I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy but silly way to solve my question but I still want to know if there is a easy way to do it.

If I know exactly how may items in players array ,I can $and all them together to get what I want, for example, if I have 10 items in players array. I can do this:

```
db.data.find({
$and :[
    {"players.0.status" : 0},
    {"players.1.status" : 0},
    {"players.2.status" : 0},
    {"players.3.status" : 0},
    {"players.4.status" : 0},
    {"players.5.status" : 0},
    {"players.6.status" : 0},
    {"players.7.status" : 0},
    {"players.8.status" : 0},
    {"players.9.status" : 0}
]
})
```

But what should I do if I have more items in players array?

Comment: As you mentioned this will work only when you know the array elements. Probably you can create the query the dynamically based on the array elements using the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `$not` operator : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not

`db.data.find({"player.status": { $elemMatch: { $ne: 0 }}})` would give you all the payers that have at least one status different from 0.

Then `db.data.find({"player.status": {$not: { $elemMatch: { $ne: 0 }}}})` would give you all the players that have all their statuses equal 0

Answer (score 0):

i ended up with the following solution for this problem:

```
db.data.find({
"players": {
    "$not": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "status": { "$ne": 0 }
            }
        }
    }
})
```